# IE11 filter attribute not supported

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-11

I tried the below code and noticed in IE11, the second circle did not appear at all. Once I removed the `filter="url(#blurMe)"` from the second `circle` tag, I was able to see the green second circle.

Is it correct that IE11 does not support this feature? Are there alternate ways of achieving this?

I looked at the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/filter and it showed unknown compatibility.

Thanks.

```
<svg width="230" height="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <filter id="blurMe">
   <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
 </filter>

 <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="green" />

 <circle cx="170" cy="60" r="50" fill="green"
          filter="url(#blurMe)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I tried with an empty filter definition and still don't see the second circle. I also tried with faOffset, but that didn't work also.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine on the IE 11 browser and I can see the 2 circles with your above-posted code.

Test code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="230" height="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <filter id="blurMe">
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
        </filter>
       
        <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="green" />
       
        <circle cx="170" cy="60" r="50" fill="green"
                 filter="url(#blurMe)" />
       </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Output on the IE 11 browser:

[image]

1. Make sure that you are using the exact code that you had posted above.
2. Try to clear the cache and again try to test the issue.
3. If the issue persists then please try to provide more information about the issue like which exact version of the IE 11 browser and which OS build you are using for making this test? Is any other code available on the page?